# Only 1 out 3 Chains are showing up on my S17 Pro

Tags: mining-hardware, miner-configuration, asic, antminer

One day only 1 out 3 chains are showing up, don't know why this is and 1 out of the 3 powersupply fans are spinning. please help me

[image]

Comment: How long has the miner been running properly (with all three chains working)?  Are you running on 120v or 240v?  What gauge wire is your power circuit using, 12 or 14?